# Using Swift, Parse and the iOS FacebookSDK, how do I obtain user's name and email at login?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

So I've been banging my head on this for a couple days now, and I'm hoping someone here could shed some light on this for me!

So I'm using Parse in my Swift project, and am looking to leverage the Facebook integration to make logging in and signing up a user pretty effortless.

I have managed to get as far as logging in a user, but the part where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to access the data that I requested with permissions.

In my AppDelegate Swift file, I have this block of code..

```
// INITIALISE FACEBOOK
    let permissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            if (error == nil) {
                println("User cancelled Facebook login")
            } else {
                println("FB Login Error \n(error)")
            }
        } else if user.isNew {
                println("User has signed in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            println("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
    })
```

Everything is all well and dandy, and I get the "User has signed in through Facebook!" message.
According to the Parse documentation, this then creates a new User object in my database.

In my database, I see that there is indeed a new user, but the only fields that are populated are..

- ObjectID - random string characters
- username - random string characters
- authData - a facebook type ID.

Not the username or email.

From what I have gathered, I need to now further leverage the FacebookSDK and GraphUser, but I really dont know exactly how.. or at least not in Swift.

The Parse documentation says

> *"The Facebook iOS SDK provides a number of helper classes for interacting with Facebook's API. Generally, you will use the FBRequest class to interact with Facebook on behalf of your logged-in user. You can read more about the Facebook SDK here.
>
>   Our library manages the user's FBSession object for you. You can simply call [PFFacebookUtils session] to access the session instance, which can then be passed to FBRequests."*

But I really dont know what to type or where to type it. :(
It feels like I'm really close with this, but I'm just hitting blanks..

If someone could be kind enough to shed some light into this (how to access the details I requested permission for, i.e. full name and email) I would be incredibly grateful!

Thank you.. :)

Comment: When user is not nil, what is `user.email` and `user.username`?

Comment: @LouFranco
this is the result.. Hope it helps something -------

    User has signed in through Facebook!, 
    user.email - nil, 
    user.username - YVjT11**********bHQcil6q

Comment: Try my answer below -- inspect the other keys of result -- this is how you do a graph request for the logged in user

Comment: Check out @Albert Vila's answer. Works perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917774/facebook-parse-sign-up-swift

Answer (score 3):

You may try this (for Swift):

```
// Obtain User Data via Facebook Login
func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name, email"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else
        {
           let userName: String = result.valueForKey("name") as! String
           let Email: String = result.valueForKey("email") as! String
           println(userName)
           println(Email)

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this: https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-id-of-a-user-logged-in-with-facebook

You get the Facebook ID with this Objective-C

```
// After logging in with Facebook
[FBRequestConnection 
  startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
  }
}];
```

Which is this in Swift (not tested)

```
FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler { connection, result, error in 
    if (!error) {
       let facebookId = result["id"]
       // use facebookID
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like this is on the right track, but that Swift version of the code fails to do anything. I did a 'if error == nil, print error', and it returned error = nil..

And I would do this below the "User has signed in through Facebook!" print statement, right?

Comment: Yes, that's where I would put it.  What is result? Is it nil?  Does it have any objects in it?

Comment: I also need help on this question, stuck on the same issue has the OP :)